# I am getting a "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" when trying to bring in data from a URL

Tags: python, nonetype

Here is my code:

```
#Import libraries
import os
import pandas as pd
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
    
# API Key from EIA
api_key = 'blah blah'
# api_key = os.getenv("EIA_API_KEY")
    
# PADD Names to Label Columns
# Change to whatever column labels you want to use.
PADD_NAMES = ['PADD 1','PADD 2','PADD 3','PADD 4','PADD 5']
# Enter all your Series IDs here separated by commas
PADD_KEY = ['PET.MCRRIP12.M',
'PET.MCRRIP22.M',
'PET.MCRRIP32.M',
'PET.MCRRIP42.M',
'PET.MCRRIP52.M']
    
# Initialize list - this is the final list that you will store all the data from the json pull. Then you will use this list to concat into a pandas dataframe. 
final_data = []
# Choose start and end dates
startDate = '2009-01-01'
endDate = '2021-01-01'
    
# Pull in data via EIA API
for i in range(len(PADD_KEY)):
    url = 'http://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key=' + api_key + PADD_KEY[i]
    r = requests.get(url)
    json_data = r.json()
        
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print('Success!')
    else:
        print('Error')
        
    df = pd.DataFrame(json_data.get('series')[0].get('data'),
                        columns = ['Date', PADD_NAMES[i]])
    df.set_index('Date', drop=True, inplace=True)
    final_data.append(df)
```

Here is my error:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-38-4de082165a0d> in <module>
         10         print('Error')
         11 
    ---> 12     df = pd.DataFrame(json_data.get('series')[0].get('data'),
         13                       columns = ['Date', PADD_NAMES[i]])
         14     df.set_index('Date', drop=True, inplace=True)
    
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Print out `json_data.get('series')` and see what your list looks like. Odds are that you're not getting anything out of your request.

Answer (score 0):

'NoneType' object is not subscriptable comes when you try to find value in a none object like df["key"] where df is None.
Do you have PADD_NAMES defined somewhere in your code. For me the error looks like the issue of your json data. have you tried printing your json data?

Comment: blackbradt - I do not get any out put when i try to print: json_data.get('series')    Abhinav Jha - I do have PADD_NAMES defined. I edited my question to show more of my code

Comment: can you just print(json_data).. if you are getting any output

Comment: Thank you - I get {'error': {'code': 'API_KEY_INVALID', 'message': 'An invalid api_key was supplied. Get one at https://api.eia.gov:443'}}     pls see what I wrote below regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

The API you are calling requires HTTPS protocol to access, try to change "http" to "https"

`https://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key=`

Consider adding some debug output to check for other errors, by changing `if...else` block like this

```
if r.status_code == 200:
    print('Success!')
else:
    print('Error')
    print(json_data)
```

Comment: Good catch. i changed it but still getting 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @new2coding pls check updated post

Comment: I already had an API key from EIA website. I just got a new one thinking maybe the key expires. However, when I put new key in I get the same error: Error
{'error': {'code': 'API_KEY_INVALID', 'message': 'An invalid api_key was supplied. Get one at https://api.eia.gov:443'}}